# YouTube API: Retrieve a list of subscriptions the user subscribed to before/after a given date

Tags: node.js, rest, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm creating a RESTful API, where some of the endpoints have to use the YouTube API to get a desired user's data and I'm struggling with one of the features for a couple of days now.

One of the features involves YouTube subscriptions and lets users assign their own data to them. The subscription data will be then stored in the API database. The issue I'm facing is, I want to retrieve the list of yet unassigned (means: not yet returned by the API) subscriptions to the user. The endpoint for the unassigned subscriptions has to be paginated since I can't respond with a potentially large object. So I want to let user specify parameters such as `page`, `per_page`.

The YouTube API responds with a paginated list of subscriptions as well.

Requesting `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]` gives me a response including fields such as `nextPageToken`, `prevPageToken`, the list of subscription objects, where each of them contains the `publishedAt` field.

The solution I was thinking about presents as following:

**To keep a track of returned subscriptions I would create following fields in the API database:**

`lastSubscriptionDate: datetime` - The oldest subscription date cached by my API

`firstSubscriptionDate: datetime` - The most recent subscription date cached by my API

`lastPageToken: string` - The last page I've requested data from, and saved `lastSubscriptionDate`

**The flow:**

1. User request `GET /subscriptions?filter=unassigned&page=[PAGE]&per_page=[PER_PAGE]`
2. Since I would request those subscriptions from the YouTube API in the chronological order (by the most recent) I have the following scenarios:

I check if the `lastSubscriptionDate` equals to the `publishedAt` of the last result on the page of `lastPageToken`,

if true => return the page of the `nextPageToken` (if exists) and update my 'tracking' data.

else =>

a) The `publishedAt` of the last result on the page is older than the cached `lastSubscriptionDate` <=> A user deleted some of his subscriptions.

b) The `publishedAt` of the last result on the page is newer than the cached `lastSubscriptionDate` <=> A user subscribed to some new YouTube channels

In both a) and b) options the best way would be to just retrieve `N` (where `N` equals to per_page parameter) subscriptions after `lastSubscriptionDate` or before the `firstSubscriptionDate` to make sure I won't skip any subscriptions in the pagination process, but I feel it's impossible to do with the current version of the YouTube API.

Am I missing something? Is there any other way I could retrieve those unassigned subscriptions from the YouTube API while being sure I didn't skip any subscription?

Comment: Does *unassigned subscription* mean a YouTube subscription that *does not **yet** have attached user data* within your database?

Comment: Now I believe, the word 'assigned' might be misleading, but in general yes, however the main issue I struggle with is how to fetch user's subscriptions from the YouTube API, which haven't been fetched yet from the YouTube API at all taking into consideration, that the results on the given page might change over time because the user can add/remove some of the subscriptions.

If I find the way to efficiently request the page containing 'unassigned'/'not fetched yet'/'unexplored' subscriptions of the given user I could repeat the process until I fetch all subscription pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from you:

> Since I would request those subscriptions from the YouTube API in the chronological order (by the most recent) [...].

The [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) API endpoint queried with `mine=true` has no parameter that would enable you to obtain [Subscription resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#resource) ordered by [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet.publishedAt).

I see no other solution, but your app to have a *refresh my subscriptions list* functionality, that the user invokes when knowing he/she changed his/her subscriptions list from within YouTube Web UI. Of course, things could be more evolved: for example, also invoke *refresh my subscriptions list* periodically without any user intervention (using a logic that you design such that it fits the general workings of your app).

This *refresh my subscription list* would then fetch all the `Subscription resources` from the YouTube Data API and match this list -- `L1` -- with the one -- `L2` -- recorded in your app's database for to obtain a diff: for each entry in the union of `L1` and `L2` attach (1) `=` to those in both lists, (2) `-` to those only existing in `L2` and (3) `+` to those only existing in `L1`.

The computed diff would then allow to update  your app's database (thus making it synchronized with the remote from YouTube).

---

**Addendum**

(I'm not sure if using the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint is worth the trouble: am only pointing it out for you to acquire knowledge about it.)

You may consider to have an optimized logic of your *refresh my subscriptions list* functionality by using the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint queried with:

- `mine=true`,
- `part=snippet,contentDetails`,
- `fields=items(snippet(type),contentDetails(subscription))`, and
- `publishedAfter=...`.

But, unfortunately, the way the API is implemented does solve only partially the *diff computation* I described above:

> [**contentDetails.subscription**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.subscription) (object)
> The subscription object contains information about a channel that a user subscribed to. This property is only present if the `snippet.type` is `subscription`.
>
> [**contentDetails.subscription.resourceId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.subscription.resourceId) (object)
> The `resourceId` object contains information that identifies the resource that the user subscribed to.
>
> [**contentDetails.subscription.resourceId.kind**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.subscription.resourceId.kind) (string)
> The type of the API resource.
>
> [**contentDetails.subscription.resourceId.channelId**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#contentDetails.subscription.resourceId.channelId) (string)
> The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the channel that the user subscribed to. This property is only present if the `resourceId.kind` is `youtube#channel`.

These quotes indicate that the API would only let you know which are *the new subscriptions* you made since the `datetime` value passed to `publishedAfter`. This data obtained from the API is only the `+` part of the diff mentioned above.

Comment: _The Subscriptions.list API endpoint queried with mine=true has no parameter that would enable you to obtain Subscription resources ordered by publishedAt_

I was playing with the API explorer, and as far as I've noticed, each page for the parameter mine=true has a list of subscription objects which seem to be sorted by publishedAt field. Isn't that behavior set by default? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation though.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but don't you think it will be very costly in a performance way to retrieve all the subscription resources from the YouTube API at once? As far as I know, the limit for the single page equals to 50 resources. That means I'd had to fetch those resources in some kind of a loop, process each resource, and then save it to the database. I think I could do it while the user logs up for the first time to the application, afterward comparing already cached results would be easier, but still, I'm afraid it might take a while to finish the process at first run.

Comment: As far as I know the workings of the API, I think is ill-advised to rely on undocumented behavior. Things change, the API itself changes and its implementation changes even if at the front the API is not modified.

Comment: For what concerns the performance, do take into account what would be the average (and maximum for that matter) number of subscriptions a regular user makes. I do think that these numbers cannot be that big (maybe 100 or 200 at most).

Comment: I think you've resolved my doubts. I personally have around 500 subscriptions on my YouTube channel, but everything around that amount might be just a pessimistic case. I'm going to try this solution and find whether it suits my expectations. Thank you!

Comment: My estimation (100 to 200) was well below your number. Still 500 is not that bad, because you don't have to fetch all subscription resources all the time; but fetch them all based on a carefully thought logic (such that, among other issues, to not impede your app's performance).